# Add compound command to if statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

Right now I have this:

```
if ! false && tsproject_match_arg "--no-publish" "${my_args[@]}"; then
    zmx npm publish
fi
```

that's a syntax error.
Does anyone know how I could negate the first command?

Comment: What exactly does the error say?  I tested `if ! false && true; then echo ok; fi` and that worked (printed `ok`) in `bash`, `zsh`, `pdksh`, and `ksh93`. What's your version of `bash`?

Comment: one sec let me check, it was a syntax error

Comment: @AlexanderMills, run it under `set -x` or check that the file doesn't have any strange characters? And [edit] to include the exact error you get? Standard `sh` would croak on the array, but otherwise that looks fine to me, too.

Comment: Also please [show us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/449735/edit) the first line ( should start `#!...`) and how you invoke the script.

Comment: A standard shell gives a syntax error for "${my_args[@]}", so you did not run this using `bash`.